# Google Funding Choices not working - googlefc.getConsentStatus() always returns UNKNOWN

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-ad-manager, gdprconsentform

Yesterday I was trying to migrate from Quantcast Choice to Google Funding Choices for GDPR / EU CMP purposes. For some reason, after prompting for consent and clicking "consent" on the message dialog, the method `googlefc.getConsentStatus()` always returns `UNKNOWN` (0).

After further investigation, it seems that no matter what kind of interaction is made with the consent message (straight up clicking the consent button, rejecting it, selecting individual vendors, etc.) `getConsentStatus()` always returns `UNKNOWN`.

Anyone has a clue on what is going on? Am i missing something?

The relevant code that I'm using:

```
 window.googlefc.callbackQueue.push({
                'CONSENT_DATA_READY':
                    function () {                     
                        let consentStatus = window.googlefc.getConsentStatus();
                        vm.log("CM_CONSENT_STATUS", consentStatus);
                        switch (consentStatus) {
                            case window.googlefc.ConsentStatusEnum.CONSENTED_TO_PERSONALIZED_ADS:
                            case window.googlefc.ConsentStatusEnum.CONSENT_NOT_REQUIRED:
                                vm.allow(true);
                                break;
                            case window.googlefc.ConsentStatusEnum.CONSENTED_TO_NON_PERSONALIZED_ADS:
                                vm.reject(true);
                                break;
                            case window.googlefc.ConsentStatusEnum.UNKNOWN:
                            case window.googlefc.ConsentStatusEnum.NO_CONSENT:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
            });
```

`window.googlefc.getConsentStatus()` ​is always returning  `window.googlefc.ConsentStatusEnum.UNKNOWN`

Answer (score 2):

This actually seems to be the expected behavior, as "window.googlefc.getConsentStatus() ​will always return window.googlefc.ConsentStatusEnum.UNKNOWN if you're using the IAB TCF v2 framework". I had the same issue and tracked the answer here on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/adops/comments/ifh6n9/anybody_using_google_funding_choices_for_gdpr_cmp/

Although I didn't find the workaround to get the googlefc.getConsentStatus() function working or an equivalent to it, I got my CMP modal working (you don't have to have this code to have this working. The only thing you really gotta do is paste the Funding Choices at the top of the head and NOT stop ad requests with (adsbygoogle=window.adsbygoogle||[]).pauseAdRequests=1; or anything else, because Funding Choices pauses ads on its own - and then starts them without reload after the consent is given)